# How to get chatbot conversation

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service, transcription

I am working on azure bot service,Bot is working properly. Once the chat is completed i need to send entire chat conversation to email as a transcript-or. How to achieve this?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how you would send the file as an e-mail, obtain the file, or create it in the first place?

Comment: no not like that. Let's assume i sent  hi message to bot, it will reply hello to user. After the closing of chat , i need to send entire messages exchanged between the user and bot  to email @pm_2

Comment: I stand to be corrected, but I don't believe there is an automatic log of the interaction; you would have to implement that yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Comment: @SagarPatil Did my answer help? If so, can you upvote/mark as answer so it helps others in the future? If not, can you clarify your question so I can try to update my answer to help?

Comment: I don't have reputations to upvote....sorry

Answer (score 2):

The Bot Framework Service does not maintain any transcripts, this is something you'd have to implement yourself in your bot. You're in luck though because the Bot Builder SDK ships a piece of middleware, [appropriately named `TranscriptLoggerMiddleware`](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.cs), that will do this for you and can be configured with a backing store of your choosing.

[A storage implementation that ships in the box is the `AzureBlobTranscriptStore`](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/AzureBlobTranscriptStore.cs) which will just append to a blob throughout the life of the conversation. However, if you want to store the transcripts using another storage mechanism then you can just implement [`ITranscriptLogger`](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ITranscriptLogger.cs) (just one method) yourself and pass that to the middleware instead.

To set up the middleware you would do the following in your startup logic:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Load the settings from config however you like
    var myAzureBlobTranscriptSettings = LoadMySettingsFromConfig();

    services.AddBot<MyBot>(options =>
    {
        // Register the middleware
        options.Middleware.Add(
           new TranscriptLogger(
               new AzureBlobTranscriptStore(
                 myAzureBlobTranscriptSettings.ConnectionString,
                 myAzureBlobTranscriptSettings.ContainerName)));
    });
}
```

Comment: how do you add the AzureBlobTranscriptStore service?